# How to exit function with errorlevel

Tags: c#, methods, return

I have a function listed out below and I am unclear on how to exit the function and / or program with a given errorlevel. I have a batch file that calls this script and I need to capture the errorlevel if there is one.

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //string emulationDefault;
            string emulationMode = "";
            string bcuFileName = args[0];
            string prodIDFileName = args[1];
            string outFileName = args[2];

            emulationMode = ParseEmulation(emulationMode, prodIDFileName);
            Console.WriteLine("default= " + emulationMode);
            Console.ReadLine();

        }

            private static string ParseEmulation(string emulationMode, string prodIDFileName)
            {
                var parser = new FileIniDataParser();
                IniData data = parser.ReadFile(prodIDFileName);

                try
                {
                    emulationMode = data["Controller1"]["EmulationDefault"].Trim();

                }
                catch (NullReferenceException)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Missing EmulationDefault value");
                    return -1;
                }

                return emulationMode.ToString();
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can declare `Main` to [return `int`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0fwzzxz2.aspx):

```
static int Main(string[] args)
{
    int exitCode = //...
    return exitCode;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

3 options:

1. Return an int from Main (as described by AlexD and others).
2. Set `Environment.ExitCode` (only if Main returns void).
3. Call `Environment.Exit(int)`. This exits the program immediately.

The latter two are useful if you want to set the exit code from within deeply nested call stack.

Answer (score 0):

The errorlevel from the returned process is the return value from the Main method when using the signature returning an `int`:

```
private static int Main(string[] args)
{
    int errorLevel = 1; /*get return code from actual processing*/
    return errorLevel;
}
```